# React Native Category + Sub-Category Tab Horizontal List snap to center

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, flatlist

What up. I want to render a couple of tab as shown in the followin picture[image]

And it was more complicated than i expected. The gist is that the parent categories are at the top and the sub categories are at the bottom. I've tried making it with Flatlist but i cant seem to scroll the items to the center and since im kind of new to react native for now i'm crying in a corner. The logic i've thought was to have thought the category states and depending on which one is active hit a callback to get the products needed to render but im not sure how to implement the ui